# how does a compiler knows which class need to be serialize

Tags: java

If I declare a class as serializable, how does compiler know that this class needs to be serialized just by using Serializable keyword.

```
public class Domain implements Comparable<Domain>, Serializable{

}
```

Comment: Because you are using `Serializable` interface? Is this a question?

Comment: um, because thats what the 'Serializable' keyword says...

Comment: Don't you remember `writeObject()` method ?

Comment: there is no "Serializable" keyword in Java, just an interface...

Answer (score 3):

Compiler will not serialize your class, you need to write a code to write/ read your object to an output stream. If the class you are trying to serialize is not implementing the interface, jvm will throw  a run time error.

As soon as you marked a class as Seriablizable by implementing Serializable interface, JVMwill treat it as a serializable class. Serialzable is marker interface, which means there are no method that need to implemented when you add this interface to your class. Marker interfaces are treated specially by JVM, just to flag it that this class is serializable.

Answer (score 0):

The serialization will occu when you actually write or read an object from or to a stream. Before that, the fact of implementing Serializable has no meaning.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Juned Ahsan's answer:

Here are the tutorials:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/advanced/persistence.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html

Here is the Javadoc:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.

Comment: Well, if you have the time to do that. I often only have time to give some pointers which should be enough. No need for spoon feeding. And I referenced an existing answer I liked.